# CSS Flip Animation on time?

Tags: html, css

Using David Walsh css flip effect for an image that suppose to change to another. But wondering If it can be triggered in say 3 seconds instead of mouseover? Sorry! Kind on a n00b to this. :(

Any response will be very appreciated :)

CSS Flip homepage: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

The Code:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000;
}

/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
width: 320px;
height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
transition: 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
z-index: 2;
/* for firefox 31 */
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Three seconds after mouse-over or three seconds after page load? You can probably just add `transition-delay: 3s;` to the selector(s) you want to delay.

Comment: Similar question to what TylerH has asked. If you are looking for the flip to be auto-triggered then you need to change the whole thing to `animation` instead of `transition`. Also, are you looking for flip every 3 seconds (or) only once after 3 seconds of page load?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your replies! I want it to flip just once three seconds after the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use CSS animations instead of transitions on hover. Using `animation-fill-mode: forwards` the animation will only play once. You'll have to alter it if you want it to flip back over. `animation-delay` is used to make it wait 3 seconds.

Here's a resource for using CSS animations: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

@keyframes flip {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-animation-name: flip;
          animation-name: flip;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
          animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

@keyframes flip {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}


/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: flip;
  animation-name: flip;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        <!-- back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I just replace my CSS with this?

Comment: No it's simplified to show you what you need. You need to add the `@keyframes` and add those properties to the `.flipper` target you already have. Then remove the code that targets hover. I put a snippet to show you but you should really attempt it yourself to learn.

Comment: Trying but can't get it to work :( I think this is far beyond my skills

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks alot! You're the best Alejalapeno!